# How to know the radius of curvature that can be achieve with a line?

Tags: geometry, curvature

I have a line, of x length. I want to have a semicircle with that length. How can I know the max and min radius I can have with that line?

Comment: What makes you think there is more than one possible radius? Do you not know a formula for the circumference of a (semi-)circle? And your title makes no sense to me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nice to meet you.

Seeing as the perimeter of a semicircle=P=P(semicircle)+P(base)=$\frac{2πr}{2}+2r$:

This can be simplified down to P=πr+2r=r(π+2). Because the perimeter, or length, of the semicircle to be the same length as a line of length x, the following is needed:

P=r(π+2)=x⇔$r=\frac{x}{π+2}$.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Here is an article found after this answer was posted:
https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-formula-for-the-radius-of-a-semi-circle.

The max radius is the min radius in flat euclidean space, but if there was a transformation in the space, perhaps a linear transformation or a hyperbolic space was introduced, this could deform the semicircle just as a line is deformed in a line integral over another surface.

However, that is not an area of study that I am used to.

Example?: [Construction of Hyperbolic Circles With a Given Radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999632/construction-of-hyperbolic-circles-with-a-given-radius)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was about just the arc of the semicircle (without the base). So in this case I used just r = x/pi.

Comment: @kevinparra . Good luck in your journey for math. I hope you have good luck in the site. I also added a bit to the answer.

Comment: You are very nice, thanks for all!!